# Difference between “improvisation” and “extempore”

Tags: differences, word-usage, confusables

What is the difference between *improvisation*[¹](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=improvisation&allowed_in_frame=0) and *extempore*[²](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=extempore&allowed_in_frame=0) and where should one use each of these terms?

Comment: Quite apart from anything else, _improvisation_ is a noun, _extemporaneous_ is an adjective and _extemporaneously_ is an adverb. If you are concerned about the semantic difference, a good dictionary should be able to help you. This is general reference, and I am voting to close.

Comment: Have you read http://english.blogoverflow.com/2012/12/you-could-look-it-up/ about definitions?

Comment: @BarrieEngland pls check my edit. I had my [homework](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) done before  posting here. Hope to see your answer. :-)

Comment: @AmandeepJiddewar Linking to an etymology doesn't really show effort in figuring out the difference, unles when you include the parts you think are relevant

Comment: Pedantic close voters please see MετάEd http://english.stackexchange.com/a/96328/14666

Comment: Amandeep, you need to **frame your questions** appropriately or they will get closed. See other posts and get ideas on how to ask a great question on ELU.

Comment: @AmandeepJiddewar It is important that you did your homework, but it is equally important to always document all your research effort in the question and explain why you still still needed help. This is a great help to people who are trying to answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Extemporaneously* means, strictly speaking “without time to prepare”, though it has also acquired a secondary meaning of “without a prepared text or notes”.[¹](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=extempore)

*Improvisation* means an act of *improvising*. To *improvise* is to “act without foresight”, that is, without seeing in advance what one will do.[²](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=improvisation)

These words are not always synonymous. Imagine a European classical musician asked to perform a set piece without warning. This musician will perform extemporaneously but without improvising. Now imagine a jazz musician asked to perform without warning. This musician will perform extemporaneously and also improvise the music itself.

Comment: Yes, MetaEd, neverthless, as an another example, during the extemporaneous speech, the speaker also uses an improvisational, +1.