# Is an impromptu speech essentially the same as, or different from, an extempore speech?

Tags: adjectives

I was taught by at least two speech professors that an impromptu speech is one that is given on the spot, with no formal preparation, whereas an extempore speech is one that is prepared in advance.  If this is so--contrary to some dictionary definitions, could the similarity between the words "extemporaneous" and "spontaneous" have created confusion in this regard (as they both contain the ending letters -aneous)?

An impromptu speech is, after all, given spontaneously.  Could an extempore/extemporaneous speech be neither strictly spontaneous nor strictly planned but an admixture of both?

(Perhaps I've answered my own question by suggesting an extempore speech has elements of both spontaneity and planning.  Having done a good deal of public speaking, I have on many occasions departed from my prepared remarks by either adding or subtracting elements in an impromptu or spontaneous way.  A sudden "brainstorm" could trigger such redacting, or even a puzzled look on the faces of my auditors(!), not to mention time constraints.)

Comment: Related: [Difference between “Improvisation” and “Extemporaneous”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96322/difference-between-improvisation-and-extemporaneous)

Comment: For a speech to be truly spontaneous it would have to be written by monkeys on typewriters. A good speaker is always in some sense "prepared" to speak. Even when not reading from a prepared speech or notes, one reads from one's memory and training.

Comment: _Impromptu_ is French for 'sudden'; _extempore_ is Latin for 'at the moment'. They're both borrowed, and they're formal categories in competitive speech events, and therefore they have a formal definition in that context. Outside that context, you can call them anything you want.

Comment: I think it's General Reference that an *extempore speech is one that is **not** prepared in advance*, so a question asking us to distinguish this from an *impromptu* speech seems pointless.

Comment: @FumbleFingers We would say an *extemporaneous speech*, since that is the category in high school forensics competitions.

Comment: @tchrist: That would be my first choice too. Not that I'd distinguish any difference in meaning - it's just that *extempore* sounds a bit "erudite/old-fashioned" to me, whereas *extemporaneous* is just a word. But my problem is OP seems to have an inverted definition of *extempore* - presumably because it's sufficiently uncommon that he's never noticed the error.

Comment: @FumbleFingers OP has a degree in rhetoric, I believe, and probably isn't inverting the meaning of extempore. In the Wikipedia article on speech competition, *impromptu* speakers are given only a few seconds or a few minutes before they speak; *extemporaneous* or *extempore* speakers are given 20 or 30 minutes to prepare.

Comment: @MετάEd: Ooops! Well I think I'd better bow out from this debate, since it clearly involves (possible) fine distinctions that I know nothing about.

Comment: @MetaEd: Thanks for your honesty. Those who voted to close would not likely have voted to close had they realized--as you did--there are "fine distinctions" they know nothing about. (I have a feeling that the closing of my question has something to do with the old and traditional antagonism between those in the camp of rhetoric and those in the camp of English. Interestingly, some--if not most--English majors aren't even aware of that antagonism. Perhaps they subconsciously know that the study of rhetoric, qua rhetoric, came first, and they are a bit defensive about that.)

Comment: @MetaEd. Moreover, rhetoric has traditionally been more closely linked to public speaking and oratory than to writing and literature. Those two linkages--the linkage between English and English composition, and between rhetoric and public speaking in the English language--is probably necessary, however, as the two disciplines are in a sense too big to "cover" easily and efficiently under the same umbrella. This is almost pure speculation on my part, but there may be a shred of truth in my speculation. Notwithstanding, to this day in academia, English and Rhetoric depts. are separate entities.

Answer (score 4):

I think consulting a corpus such as COCA or BNC or Google Books will quickly satisfy you that general usage makes no such distinction between *extempore* and *impromptu* as that you describe. Both mean essentially “improvised” or “unprepared” without further qualification.

This is not by any means to say that your Speech professors misinformed you, merely that that discipline requires a fine distinction which the larger speech community does not ordinarily find any need to draw.

A distinction which you *will* find is that *impromptu* has a wider range of reference than *extempore*: *extempore* is largely (but not entirely) confined to performances (speech, debate, remarks, questions), whereas *impromptu* is also used of events and activities (an impromptu concert, party, meeting, meal, tour, shoot, lesson), of performing persons (an impromptu squad, team, trio), and of objects (an impromptu kite, table, kiln). But it's not clear whether this wider reference is inherent or merely a function of more widespread use.

Answer (score 4):

As both a high school and collegiate forensicator, these are the distinctions I followed. They were roughly the same (times varied by a couple minutes)  in both high school and college.

**Impromptu Speaking**: A speaker was given 6 minutes to prepare and deliver a speech on one of three topics presented to him. The amount of time devoted to prepping and to speaking was up to the speaker, but the adjudicator could (and commonly would) dock speaker points from someone who prepped for more than 1 minute. The speaker could not write anything down during prep time.

**Extemporaneous Speaking**: A speaker was given 3 current event-based topics to choose from. After choosing a topic the speaker had 30 minutes to use his team's research library to prepare a 7-minute speech. The speaker could use notes from his research time in his speech.

The main distinctions between the two speeches and, perhaps, between the two words are the following: an "extemp" speech is less spontaneous than an impromptu speech and allows the use of notes. An impromptu speech is done  *all of a sudden* while an extemp speech is *premeditated but unrehearsed*.

Comment: This distinction follows what I learned as a member of Toastmasters: an impromptu speech is one where there is no time to prepare at all; an exteporaneous speech allows the speaker to at least prepare a mental outline, but the body of the speech is supposed to be unrehearsed. This distinction is further echoed in [this newspaper column](http://www.deseretnews.com/article/659254/Extemporaneous-impromptu-not-precisely-alike.html).

Answer (score 3):

The opinion of speech professors that “an impromptu speech is one that is given on the spot, with no formal preparation, whereas an extempore speech is one that is prepared in advance” is correct in a limited context, in spite of dictionary definitions that suggest *extempore* means  “carried out with no preparation; impromptu” ([1](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/extempore#Adjective), [2](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/extempore), 
[3](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/extempore), 
[4](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/extempore)).

The context where preparation is relevant is that of competitive *[extemporaneous speaking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extemporaneous_speaking)*, in which a 30-minute preparation period is allowed before a 7-minute speech is given.  In addition, competitors typically will have read in advance numerous articles in the subjects they know will be considered; they will have made notes, practiced speaking on common topics, etc.